# Spawn interactive process and exit in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, bash, command-line, spawn

I'm trying to accomplish (I think) a fairly simple thing, but couldn't find any existing answers, so here it goes.

I would like to imitate the following bash script in node:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
mysql
```

so basically exactly like typing 'mysql' in the command line. So far I came up with the following:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('/usr/bin/mysql', [], {stdio: 'inherit', detached: true});
child.unref();
```

which works ok (presents me with the mysql prompt), but when I type a command it gets sent to the bash command line not the mysql.
I've tried other stdio options (pipe, ignore) with listeners on stdout, stderr etc, but this got me as far as hanging empty prompt. Any and all suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Why the down vote? I'm guessing because it's to specific, but on the other hand you can replace 'mysql' with any kind of interactive shell command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried without `detached: true`? It should work with stdio set to `inherit` and detached not set in the options

Comment: Duh :0 I've tried so many combinations that I really thought this one didn't work either.. You're right, getting rid of detached and unref() works. Thanks!